# ¿Como Mostrar datos en mi vista con viewbag C#-ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, linq, razor

Buen dia estoy intentando mostrar una lista de datos en mi vista, los datos los mando desde mi controlador por medio de un viewbag pero muestra el codigo mas no el dato

Primer forma de obtención de datos:

```
       var software = from f in db.Eq_tblMantenimientoSoftware
                                       where f.Eq_tblMantenimiento_id == id
                                       select new { name = f.Eq_tblSoftware.Nombre };
   
 ViewBag.software =software ;
```

Segunda manera de obtención de datos:

```
   ViewBag.software = db.Eq_tblMantenimientoSoftware.Where(x => x.Eq_tblMantenimiento_id == id).Select(x => x.Eq_tblSoftware.Nombre);
```

en mi vista:

```
    @foreach (var dato in ViewBag.software)
    {
       <div>
           @ViewBag.software
       </div>
    }
```

y el resultado es:

SELECT [Extent2].[Nombre] AS [Nombre] FROM [dbo].[Eq_tblMantenimientoSoftware] AS [Extent1] INNER JOIN [dbo].[Eq_tblSoftware] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Eq_tblSoftware_id] = [Extent2].[id] WHERE [Extent1].[Eq_tblMantenimiento_id] = @p__linq__0

cuando quisiera me imprimiera en mi vista: Valor1 , Valor2 , Valor 3

alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: porque no usas un modelo?

Answer (score 0):

Conseguí lo que quería haciendo lo siguiente cabe aclarar que esto sucede por que tengo una tabla intermedia para poder trabajar de manera optima en una Entidad-Relacion de muchos a muchos

en mi controlador seria la consulta usando ya sea la que utilizo ahora o la de linq ambas funcionan

```
        var software = from f in db.Eq_tblMantenimientoSoftware
                       where f.Eq_tblMantenimiento_id == id
                       select new { name = f.Eq_tblSoftware.id };
        ViewData["software"] = software;
```

o la que use fue

```
        ViewBag.software = db.Eq_tblMantenimientoSoftware.Where(x => x.Eq_tblMantenimiento_id == id).Select(x => x.Eq_tblSoftware.Nombre);
```

En la vista

```
  <dl class="row">

        <dt class="col-md-1">
            Software:
        </dt>
       
        @foreach (var dato in ViewBag.software)
        {
            <dd class="col-md-1">
                @dato
            </dd>
        }
    </dl>
```

espero le sirva a alguien mas